# Success modal after submting a modal form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, modal-dialog

I finished all my website forms coding, and I want to add a success modal message when submitting the forms, now some of my forms are already in models submitted by ajax, I want to call the success modal on the same page, it is not working for me, though the modal is working when I put it outside if(isset($_POST['post_button'])) statement.

here is my code

```
     <form action="" method="post" class="profile_post3 registration-form">
      <fieldset>

        <p style="color: #580024;">Error</p>
        <textarea rows="1" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control  btn-" name="error1"></textarea><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" name="post_button" id="submit_profile_post3"><p style="color: #580024; margin-bottom: 0px;">Submit</p></button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">clos</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>



    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['post_button'])) {
    echo "   <script>
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>";
    } ?>


    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade'>
      <div class='modal-dialog modal-confirm'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
            <div class='icon-box'>
              <i class='material-icons'>&#xE876;</i>
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class='modal-body text-center'>
            <h4>Great!</h4> 
            <p>Your Message Has Been Reported.</p>
            <button class='btn btn-success' data-dismiss='modal'><span>Done</span> <i class='material-icons'>&#xE5C8;</i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
  if(isset($_POST['post_button'])) {
    echo "   <script>
        $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>";
} ?>
```

and this in your ajax success function, add this

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

which will trigger after POST data have been processed.

I will let you figure the rest by yourself.

Comment: I added it as the following:

   success: function(msg) {
    $("#post_form3").modal('hide');
    location.reload();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

what happened is when submitting the 1st modal the success modal appears and then the page reloads and it disappears

Comment: I have another big problem here is that, I am having a number of forms on the same ajax function :( 
so if your solution worked, the success message has to be the same for all forms related to the same ajax function